# triggering the code pipeline only if user creates a tag in the code repo

Tags: commit, pipeline, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to configure the cloud watch event pattern for invoking the codepipeline when user creates a tag in the code commit repository? 
Or there is any way for restricting user to not run the pipeline on every commit?

Answer (score 6):

Answering a rather old question, you can create a CloudWatch event to trigger the CodePipeline only on a tag creation. Make sure to use CloudWatch event as the "Change detection options" and delete/disable any events pre/auto configured to trigger on commits.

You can use a rule similar to following, [Described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/triggering.html)

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.codecommit"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "CodeCommit Repository State Change"
  ],
  "resources": [
    "<Your repository ARN>"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "event": [
      "referenceCreated"
    ],
    "repositoryName": [
      "<Your repository name>"
    ],
    "referenceType": [
      "tag"
    ]
  }
}
```

Also, [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html) describes all available CloudWatch event types.

Comment: Are `referenceType` types documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is currently supported by CodePipeline.

What I did to get the same effect is let the pipeline run as usual and in the build step (I was using CodeBuild in this instance but it applies to any CI tool e.g. Jenkins) I immediately check if the commit is tagged using git commands and abort the build if it isn't.

It's obviously less than ideal but it does get the job done.

Comment: This has a downside that you might miss builds. If multiple commits are pushed at once, say A, B and C (where C is the head, but A is the tagged commit), you'll miss the tag build. CodePipeline will only run for the head commit at the time of the push.

Comment: Yes, like I said, less than ideal. Also, what you are describing holds true for commits as well i.e. commits will be “missed” too if pushed together. So not specific to tags per se. You can search for the tag you want and get the right revision to build after having cloned the repo (with sufficient depth) anyway.

Comment: I feel like commits aren't really missed, because they're included in the history (although, yes, they're not built individually). Did you end up solving the potentially-missed-tag problem?

Comment: I ended up using git to grab the “commit for tag X” in the buildspec